# set date with current year as public const

Tags: excel, vba, constants

i wish to set a date with fixed dd and mm but but current year, for eg 01/01/2018 or 31/01/2018, 05/08/2018 (in us dd and mm are reversed) and so on.
hello guys, i wish to set a date with fixed dd and mm but but current year, for eg 01/01/2018 or 31/01/2018, 05/08/2018 (in us dd and mm are reversed) and so on.
i know only number and string can be set as public const;

thereby i tried so far:

```
Public Const gen1 As Long = CLng(#1/1/year(date)#)
```

but is not working
any tip please?
thanks

Answer (score 2):

A public property should also be just fine:

```
Public Property Get TheDate() As Date
    TheDate = DateSerial(Year(Date), 1, 1)
End Property
```

Then just call it:

```
Debug.Print TheDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Constants cannot have variables in them, and in VBA, you cannot Dim a variable and assign it's value at the same time like you are doing (You can in VB.NET tho).

It would be written more like this:

```
Public gen1 As Long 
gen1 = CLng(#1/1/year(date)#)
```

But that's going to give you an error too...

If you are trying to assign the value of gen1 to be the current year, all you need is this:

```
gen1 = Year(Date)
```

If you want January 1 of the current year as a Date (not a Long) then you can do it like this:

```
Dim gen1 as Date
gen1 = CVDate("1/1/" & Year(Date))
```